# Jersey 2.4 and CXF 2.6

Tags: java, tomcat, cxf, dependency-management, jersey-2.0

I have implemented an API integration with Jersey 2.4 but i have a problem when try to start my tomcat

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
```

maybe there is a conflict on use of UriBuilder that it's referenced in javax.ws.rs.core and UriBuilderImpl in org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl. If i rename cxf-2.6.0.jar in my WEB-INF\lib as zxf-2.6.0.jar (to load as last), all works fine.

How could i solve that problem in an elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely UriBuilder **conflict** and when you rename cxf jar you change lookup order making correct version to come first. I would recommend to use **Maven** for dependency management where one can use *exclude* tag for unwanted sub-dependency.

Comment: but my project it's not mavenized…how could i solve in another way?

Comment: How it's possible to do it?

Comment: Use **zip** of **jar**. Every OS requires special way to do it.